# Converting Date Components (Integer) to String

Tags: swift, xcode6

My code takes an NSDate and reads year, month, and day, then strings them together as a single integer. I next want to convert this Int to a String, so that it can be inserted into a URL String, but without success:

```
let calendarUnits: NSCalendarUnit = .CalendarUnitDay | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitYear
let components = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(calendarUnits, fromDate: dateToBeExamined)
var dateInt = components.year
dateInt += components.day
dateInt += components.month
var dateString = dateInt as! String
```

I have tried several methods, including the following:

```
"\(dateInt)"
dateInt.description
dateInt as String
String(dateInt)
```

However, all of them tell me that "Int is not convertible to String", or, with an "!" after the "as", that "Int cast to String will always fail". Does anyone have a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first - several - attempt is correct

```
let dateString = "\(dateInt)"
```

or the "sophisticated" version

```
let dateString = String(stringInterpolationSegment: dateInt)
```

Edit: but you might want to concatenate the string values rather than performing a mathematical addition, then use the syntax of the answer of zaph.

Comment: Odd. It hadn't worked before, but I tried it again now and it works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
let dateString = "\(components.year)\(components.day)\(components.month)"
println("dateString: \(dateString)")
```

Output:

> dateString: 2015118

or

```
let dateString = String(components.year) + String(components.day) + String(components.month)
```