# Convert Date to Integer in Swift

Tags: swift, date, time, integer

I am updating some of my old Swift 2 answers to Swift 3. [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37699089/3681880) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27059292/convert-nsdate-to-an-integer), though, is not easy to update since the question specifically asks for `NSDate` and not `Date`. So I am creating a new version of that question that I can update my answer for.

**Question**

If I start with a `Date` instance like this

```
let someDate = Date()
```

how would I convert that to an integer?

**Related but different**

These questions are asking different things:

- [Swift convert unix time to date and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26849237/swift-convert-unix-time-to-date-and-time)
- [Converting Date Components (Integer) to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31948226/converting-date-components-integer-to-string)
- [Convert Date String to Int Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33202466/convert-date-string-to-int-swift)

Answer (score 118, accepted):

## `Date` to `Int`

```swift
// using current date and time as an example
let someDate = Date()

// convert Date to TimeInterval (typealias for Double)
let timeInterval = someDate.timeIntervalSince1970

// convert to Integer
let myInt = Int(timeInterval)
```

Doing the `Double` to `Int` conversion causes the milliseconds to be lost. If you need the milliseconds then multiply by 1000 before converting to `Int`.

## `Int` to `Date`

Including the reverse for completeness.

```swift
// convert Int to TimeInterval (typealias for Double)
let timeInterval = TimeInterval(myInt)

// create NSDate from Double (NSTimeInterval)
let myNSDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timeInterval)

I could have also used `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` instead of `timeIntervalSince1970` as long as I was consistent. This is assuming that the time interval is in seconds. Note that Java uses milliseconds.
```

## Note

- For the old Swift 2 syntax with `NSDate`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37699089/3681880).

Comment: Good point about Java, this is why you cannot really convert Date to Integer in Java, because it is simply not large enough to hold such values. In Java you'd need to use long for this. Refernce: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12067697/convert-current-date-as-integer

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for ***timestamp*** with **`10 Digit seconds since 1970`** for **API** call then, below is code:

**Just 1 line code for Swift 4/ Swift 5**

**`let timeStamp = UInt64(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)`**

`print(timeStamp)`   <-- prints current time stamp

1587473264

```
let timeStamp = UInt64((Date().timeIntervalSince1970) * 1000) // will give 13 digit timestamp in milli seconds
```

Comment: Can use for API call, as they expect 10 digit time stamp above code should serve the purpose

Comment: This is incorrect. `Date().timeIntervalSince1970` will return a Double value in seconds. If you want it to be in milliseconds you need to multiply by 1000. Either way, you still need to convert it to a Int64: `Int64(timeStamp * 1000)`.

Answer (score 1):

`timeIntervalSince1970` is a relevant start time, convenient and provided by Apple.

If u want the int value to be smaller, u could choose the relevant start time you like

```
extension Date{
    var intVal: Int?{
        if let d = Date.coordinate{
             let inteval = Date().timeIntervalSince(d)
             return Int(inteval)
        }
        return nil
    }


    // today's time is close to `2020-04-17 05:06:06`

    static let coordinate: Date? = {
        let dateFormatCoordinate = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatCoordinate.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        if let d = dateFormatCoordinate.date(from: "2020-04-17 05:06:06") {
            return d
        }
        return nil
    }()
}


extension Int{
    var dateVal: Date?{
        // convert Int to Double
        let interval = Double(self)
        if let d = Date.coordinate{
            return  Date(timeInterval: interval, since: d)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Use like this:

```
    let d = Date()

    print(d)
    // date to integer, you need to unwrap the optional
    print(d.intVal)

    // integer to date
    print(d.intVal?.dateVal)
```